# Can I connect 2 Gigabit lan connections between 2 switches?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, gigabit-ethernet

I have 2 switches (one functions as a router with the broadband connection) both of them have 4 gigabit ports.

Currently they are connected with a single cat6 lan cord and work fine...

I would like to increase the connection and thoughts about connecting a 2nd cord between them.
Will that increase the speed to 2GB? Does this configuration can at all take advantage of 2 simultaneous/parallel connections?

Comment: What make and model are the switches? Do they have any trunking features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to configure BOTH switches to bundle the double link into a single connection.

If you don't configure the switches 2 things can happen:

- the switches will only use 1 of the links and consider the other as "backup"
- worse: it creates a loop situation which will cause all sorts of havoc in your LAN.

How to do this varies greatly with make and model of the switches.
If you can't configure this in the switches forget about the idea altogether.
(Considering that you claim one is also a broadband router, it seems that this is consumer gear. Most of those can't be configured for dual-link operation.)